# Bienvenida is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Tags: java

Muy buenas. Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en java y tengo el siguiente error.

> "Bienvenida is not abstract and does not override abstract method
> actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in
> java.awt.event.ActionListener".

Dejo el código a continuación, gracias.

```java
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;


    public class Bienvenida extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 
   //ActionaListener --> para crear un evento desde un boton
        
        //creacion de componentes
        private JTextField textfield1;
        private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4;
        private JButton boton1;
        
        
        //constructor de componentes
        public Bienvenida(){
            setLayout(null); //metodo para poder usar coordenadas
            
            setTitle("Bienvenido"); //titulo de la ventana
            getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,0,0)); //cambiando fondo de la interfaz 
            
            setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("D:/java-2021-03/VACASCOCACOLA/images/icon.png")).getImage());
                
        }
        
        //constructor principal
        static void main(String args[]){
            
            Bienvenida ventana = new Bienvenida();
            
            ventana.setVisible(true);
            ventana.setResizable(false);
            ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mensaje es claro: la clase `Bienvenida` no es abstracta por lo que está obligada a implementar el método `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` que le transmite la interfaz `ActionListener`.

Para solucionar esto simplemente debes immplementar dicho método.

```
public class Bienvenida extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    ...
 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        // Implementación concreta del listener
    }

    ...
}
```